# need to get current location after GPS is ON using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp00e.jpg)I am using xamarin forms for my app. I turn off the GPS for my device and i launch my app. The following method(getcurrentlocation) execute first and the current location latitude and longitude comes 0,0 and then My app is showing like attached image.

I need the following:
When I click "Ok" on the dialog box, then only the following method(getcurrentlocation) need to execute.
Can any one please help me to resolve this issue.

Farm.xaml.cs:

```
 public FarmLoad()
{
InitializeComponent();
getcurrentlocation();
}

public async Task getcurrentlocation()
        {
            try
            {
                var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                locator.DesiredAccuracy = 500;
                var position = await locator.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
                if (position != null)
                {
                    Constants.CurrentsLat = position.Latitude;
                    Constants.CurrentsLng = position.Longitude;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: could you add a button to call method manually?

Comment: Did you try to use the PositionChanged event? I didn't try, but I believe when you allow your service to get the location it will automatically update.

Comment: hI Daniel and Leo, thank you for your help. i have put button for this.